# Why does :new create a split?

Tags: buffers, split

Why does :new create a split? What is the use case for that functionality?

Normally when I open a new scratch buffer, I don't want it to be in a split.

Answer (score 4):

By definition `:new` creates a new buffer in a new window (aka split). From `:h :new`:

> Create a new window and start editing an empty file in it.

I imagine `:enew` might be more appropriate if you just want a new/scratch buffer in the current window.

For more help see:

```
:h :new
:h window
:h :enew
```

Comment: Ok, so it is making a new window, not a new buffer. Is there no command to create a new buffer in the existing window?

Comment: @TylerDurden, `:enew` does exactly that. See `:h :enew`

Comment: Well, according to you, new creates a WINDOW, not a buffer.

Comment: @TylerDurden if you read the `:help new` documentation, further it has *"This behaves like a ":split" first, and then an ":enew" command."*. Also, it's not just "according to Peter", this is the official help that says it creates a new window. But more specifically it clearly creates an empty buffer and a new window that's pointing to that buffer.

Comment: Ok, well let's get back to the original question: what is the use case for :new?

Comment: @TylerDurden normally when I want a scratch buffer, I want it in a split, as I want to see the current file too.

Comment: The use case is exactly that: Open a new buffer in a new window. If you want it to open in the current window, use the `:enew` command